# Bitbucket Pipelines - Is there a way to see a build monitor?

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

We are starting to use Bitbucket Pipelines after previously using Jenkins as our CI server.

The only thing that's missing now is a build monitor, something similar to the Jenkins Build Monitor seen here: [link](https://github.com/jan-molak/jenkins-build-monitor-plugin)

Does anyone know of an equivalent for Pipelines? I suppose I could always create my own using the [Bitbucket Repositories API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories) and an open source build monitor framework [like this](https://github.com/marcells/node-build-monitor#theming-support), but I'd rather not do that unless I have to.

Thanks!

Comment: As of November 2018 the framework you mention [supports Bitbucket Pipelines](https://github.com/marcells/node-build-monitor#bitbucket-pipelines).